# Xamarin.Forms-beta-2.3.4-pre1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT\ImageRenderer.cs\Line59 NullReference Exception

Tags: xamarin.forms

## Steps to reproduce

Resize a xamarin.forms page while adding/remove image in that page with a thread

## Expected behavior

works properly

## Actual behavior

Unhandled NullReferenceException.

## Supplemental info (logs, images, videos)

\Xamarin.Forms-beta-2.3.4-pre1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT\ImageRenderer.cs\Line59.  After await UpdateSource(), Control may became null. should add a null check before call UpdateAspect.

```
protected override async void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
                image.ImageOpened += OnImageOpened;
                image.ImageFailed += OnImageFailed;
                SetNativeControl(image);
            }

            await UpdateSource();
            UpdateAspect();
        }
    }
```

## Test environment (full version information)

Answer (score 0):

If you've found a bug for Xamarin Forms I suggest you post it on [Xamarins Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug?product=Forms&target_milestone=---).